# in nodejs app how to use dotenv and config?

Tags: node.js, config, dotenv

I am new to development, i understand that dotenv create environment variables that we don't want to expose in our code , while config create similar variables to be used by app for configuration however I am little confused about use case. could you explain it a little or point me to further resource for better understanding. and is there any other similar packages that create environment variables and how are they used ?

Answer (score 5):

The way I do it is using both [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) packages.

You'd create a .env file (which you'll add to .gitignore)

For example

```
client_id='1234'
client_secret='XXXXX'
```

Then you create a folder called config at the root of your project, and inside it a file `default.js`

In this file you'll add first

`require('dotenv').config();`

and then you can export js friendly variables

```
require('dotenv').config(); 

export const client = {
    clientId: process.env.client_id,
    clientSecret: process.env.client_secret
}
```

Finally you can use these in your index.ts for example

```
import config from 'config';

console.log(config.get('client'));
// { clientId: '1234', clientSecret: 'XXXXX'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm package for this use case

create a .env file in your project something similar to:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

then you can configure your file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, './config.env') })
```

then you can use them like:

```
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```